# Model Admin Search - Override the search string

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a phone number field in a ModelForm which users can search for in admin. The problem is that they are lazy and don't want to enter in the dashes in the phone numbers.

If I search for '555-555-5555' all the objects with that phone number will return

If I search '5555555555', I get zero results.

Is there anyway to override or just alter the search string that gets submitted? If so I planned on doing something like

```
if search_string.isdigit() and len(search_string) == 10:
    search_string = '-'.join(
        (search_string[:3],search_string[3:6],search_string[6:])
    )
```

I see in Django 1.6 there is a [get_search_results method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) that might be useful but I'm running on 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to achieve this by overriding `get_changelist` within my ModelAdmin. Found a useful blog post that led me to the answer: [Override ModelAdmin ChangeList](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/django-override-modeladmin-changelist-ordering-by-annotate-and-aggregate/)

```
def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):                                 
    # Allow users to not have to enter in '-' when searching by phone #      
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList                   

    class NewChangeList(ChangeList):                                         
        def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):                            
            query = self.query                                               
            if query.isdigit() and len(query) == 10:                         
                self.query = '-'.join((query[:3], query[3:6], query[6:]))    

            return super(NewChangeList, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs) 

    return NewChangeList
```